# PhoneGap App not working with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, google-analytics

I am using the analytics.js to track the user activity using the code in web app.

Now Phonegap app ios/android is built and want to track the user activity in Phonegap app also, but it is not giving the tracking results I have read and implemented the solutions as in

[Phonegap google analytics not tracking at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020856/phonegap-google-analytics-not-tracking-at-all)

https://github.com/blast-analytics-marketing/phonegap-google-universal-analytics

My Problem is: both in native using phonegap and web app uses same set of pages , I would like to track the same pages both under single GA account using Dimension, but I am not able to do in phone gap.

Could anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
          var ua="UA-XXXXXXX-Y";
          ga('create', ua, {'storage': 'none','clientId': "123"});
          ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null);
          ga('set','checkStorageTask',null);
```

Comment: Have you whitelisten the Google url?

Comment: This plugin (https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) is specific for running GA in cordova mobile apps, maybe helps you.

Comment: @jcarrera: it is using the mobile app property in my analytics account...i want to track under same property as web app since in app and web pages are same. I am differentiating the users from app using dimension.

Comment: @Joerg: which url to whitelist and where it place?

Comment: Sometimes docs are helping: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html read also the docs from the whitelist-plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After Two days, Found [solution from the Google Group Phonegap page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/phonegap/google$20analytics/phonegap/Mtj6KoUk8cY/1oPJ-UEhpBIJ) , This answer worked for me. thanks Mayor, his answer is

```js
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','gaU');
gaU('create','UA-XXXXXXXX-X',{'storage':'none','clientId':device.uuid});
gaU('set','checkProtocolTask',null);
gaU('set','anonymizeIp',true);
gaU('set','forceSSL',true);
gaU('send','pageview',{'title':'I heart Cordova','page':'/cordova'});
gaU('send','event',{'eventCategory':'My_Category','eventAction':'My_Action','eventLabel':'Event_Label','eventValue':11});
```

notes:

- you must set the url for google-analytics.com to use http or https (the default has // which tries to load file:// which does not work)
- use must turn off 'storage' and add a clientId which you can use the Cordova device.uuid
- you must disable protocol checking (because file:// does not work) by setting checkProtocolTask to null
- this only works with the new "Universal" analytics.  your GA account must be created as "Website" rather than "Mobile App"

Comment: In my case, the `'storage' : 'none'` was crucial to make it work on Android/Chrome, but I can't really figure why.

Comment: This: `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', { 'storage': 'none' });` and this: `ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null);` worked for me. Why? **(1)** [Setting `storage` to `none` disables cookies usage which is unavailable using Phonegap](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#disabling_cookies) **(2)** [Setting `checkProtocolTask` to `null` disables the check for `http` and `https` protocol thus allowing `file` protocol, which is used by Phonegap, to pass](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#disabling_a_task).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this has been explicitly disallowed in the more recent versions of Google Analytics. They say clearly in their docs now:

> Use Analytics in a WebView on Android
>
> Calls to log events or set user properties fired from within a WebView must be forwarded to native code before they can be sent to app reports in Google Analytics.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/android/webview